# theano import error in linux using python3.6 when using cpu as config device

Tags: python, linux, pip, cpu, theano

I have installed theano with python3.6 using pip install theano and Getting below error while importing theano even though I configured theano to run with cpu.

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py", line 75, in 
>       raise ImportError()
>   ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py", line 92, in 
>       raise ImportError()
>   ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/**init**.py", line 66, in 
>       from theano.compile import (
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/**init**.py", line 10, in 
>       from theano.compile.function_module import *
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 21, in 
>       import theano.compile.mode
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/compile/mode.py", line 10, in 
>       import theano.gof.vm
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/vm.py", line 662, in 
>       from . import lazylinker_c
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/lazylinker_c.py", line 127, in 
>       preargs=args)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 2316, in compile_str
>       (status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
>   Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC. /usr/local/lib/libpython3.6m.a: error adding symbols: Bad value. collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python C binding error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28511138/python-c-binding-error)

Comment: If python c binding is the case there will be error while importing other python modules as well.I am having issues only in importing theano

Comment: The advice **recompile with -fPIC** is right on the screen, that's why the question is a dup.

Comment: got the solution,the problem raised due to partial installation of python3.6-dev and python3.6